# Stop Syntax-Checkers Complaining About Scons

Tags: python, syntax-error, scons

When I am writing SConstruct files in an editor that reports syntax errors, inevitably they always complain about the SCons-specific method calls such as `Program()` and `Object()`. To the syntax-checker, these would be an error when run as a regular Python script, which is completely true. The syntax-checker is unaware of the *magic* that scons performs when running the SConstruct file. Some of them can be quite bothersome when they detect an error.

Is there a Python module I can import, or other technique I can use to make these syntax-checkers happy, without changing the behavior of the SConstruct file? I'd prefer not to have to modify the individual settings of the syntax-checker, if possible.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the answer may depend on which syntax checker you are using. Can you be more explicit about that?

Comment: @bdbaddog My primary editor is Vim with [spf13](http://vim.spf13.com/) installed, which includes the [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) syntax checker. Unless I missed something, my understanding is that I would need to disable or heavily modify the regular python syntax checking to make it stop complaining about Scons. I was hoping there might be a way to make the SConstruct into "valid" Python (as far as the syntax checker is concerned) instead, without changing how the SConstruct works.